# .match() problems with regex

Tags: jquery, regex

I have some text that i get returned from a method in the format like this:

```
"Title B-17G Flying Fortress Country United States of America Rank 4 Rating 6 Max altitude 11156 m Max speed 510.12 km/h on altitude 7680 m Turn time 36 s Take on distance 600 m Climb time 1680 s to altitude 7620 m Climb rate 4.5 m/s Time for free repair 108 h 16 m Max repair cost 6140 s.l. Cost 210000 s.l."
```

So basically, from the above, I need to extract:

```
"B17G Flying Fortress", "United States of America", "4", "6", " 11156 m", "510.12 km/h on altitude 7620 m", ...
```

Ideas?

Comment: What's the problem exactly? It doesn't appear you're using `match()` *anywhere*.

Comment: Please show us what you have tried

Comment: Good Luck with that! Better go further back upstream to there the data has some structure

Answer (score 2, accepted):

If the sequence of fields will remain constant you can try something like this:

```
Title\s*(.*?)\s*Country\s*(.*?)\s*Rank\s*(.*?)\s*Rating\s*(.*?)\s*Max altitude\s*(.*?)\s*Max speed\s*(.*?)\s*Turn time\s*(.*?)\s*Take on distance\s*(.*?)\s*Climb time\s*(.*?)\s*Climb rate\s*(.*?)\s*Time for free repair\s*(.*?)\s*Max repair cost\s*(.*?)\s*Cost\s*(.*?)\s*$
```

[Sample](https://regex101.com/r/dQ8xT2/1)

```
var re = /Title\s*(.*?)\s*Country\s*(.*?)\s*Rank\s*(.*?)\s*Rating\s*(.*?)\s*Max altitude\s*(.*?)\s*Max speed\s*(.*?)\s*Turn time\s*(.*?)\s*Take on distance\s*(.*?)\s*Climb time\s*(.*?)\s*Climb rate\s*(.*?)\s*Time for free repair\s*(.*?)\s*Max repair cost\s*(.*?)\s*Cost\s*(.*?)\s*$/gm; 
var str = 'Title B-17G Flying Fortress Country United States of America Rank 4 Rating 6 Max altitude 11156 m Max speed 510.12 km/h on altitude 7680 m Turn time 36 s Take on distance 600 m Climb time 1680 s to altitude 7620 m Climb rate 4.5 m/s Time for free repair 108 h 16 m Max repair cost 6140 s.l. Cost 210000 s.l..';
var subst = '$1, $2, $3, $4, $5, $6, $7, $8, $9'; 

var result = str.replace(re, subst);
```

Otherwise, you could try the same regex with alternation

Comment: Ty, this works as expected. I found another way as well. The data is coming from a table, where the "Title" is the first of two `td`'s in a `tr`, the other being the value needed. Using `var text = $('.flight-parameters td:contains("Country")').next().text();` grabs the approriate value, but obvously i'd have to loop through this for the values.